# split a string saved on a pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

**I can't understand why this piece of code works:**

```
int main() {

    char *a = "Hello";
    printf("this is %s      ",a);

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
        printf("this is : %c    ",a[i]);
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. in the FOR loop, why can I refer to the *a as an array?
2. is/where it more advisable to use an array to represent a an array or a pointer.

Thank you for your help.

Mike

Comment: I would recommend picking up a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of randomly asking about basic language features. They should explain why you can do `a[i]` with a pointer.

Comment: Question 2 is totally unclear to me.

Answer (score 3):

In C all literal strings are really arrays of characters including the null-terminator. And as an array, it of course can decay to a pointer to its first element.

So when you do

```
char *a = "Hello";
```

you initialize `a` to point to the first element of that array (i.e. first character in the string).

You could think of it something like

```
char compiler_internal_array[] = "Hello";

char *a = &compiler_internal_array[0];
```

---

Also, for any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`. So any array indexing is really pointer arithmetic and pointer dereference.

Comment: Maybe apply `const` to `char compiler_internal_array[]` since string literals are readonly as you said?

Comment: @Trickzter That's problematic since string literal arrays *aren't* `const`, but they should be considered read-only since attempting to modify one leads to undefined behavior. Removed that part from my answer.

Comment: Learning something new every day, thanks!